# Recurring work weeks

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am working on a web tool where the user can see who works certain dates.

Have a look at this picture of an example schedule.

[image: example schedule]

Let's say that this planned schedule starts Week 1 2017. **Monday in week 1** we can read from the table that **employee 1 and 2 works 0800-1500** and **emplyee 3 and 4 works 1900-2300**. **Employee 5 and 6 have the day off**. Next week they all skip down one line.

We can read that **Monday in week 2, employee 1 and 2 works 1900-2300, employee 3 and 4 have the day off, employee 5 and 6 works 0800-1500.**

I hope this gives a clear concept of how this table works, cause here comes my question:

How would the best practice be to script this so that the user can look up any date and see who is working. The schedule changes two-three times a year; should this info be saved in a database or maybe a xml-file?

Since the schedule is repeated every third week my thought was to script it so that when the user looks up a certain date, javascript checks how many times the roster has been repeated (as integer) and then uses the modulo to create a "offset". So if employee 1 asks for Monday in week 10 (3x3)+1=10. The +1 is used as the offset to show who is actually working.

I'm quite new to programming/scripting in general, does anybody have any suggestions to what technique to use for this issue?

I plan to use html 5, css, javascript, php and sql.

Comment: in my opinion you can do all with a database and a backoffice to change values in your database

Comment: I strongly recommend you to start with better analysis - read something about "use case analysis" and "collaboration diagrams". Main question is not how to program it. But what results and advantages for end users are expected. The worst case is to start with making a data model without proper analysis.

Comment: @MacBooc: Thank you, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: @JosMac: Thank you for your suggestion, I do see your point and it's probably IT101. This project is mostly for learning and to gain experience with techniques. Right now I'm just looking for ways to do this specific task.